# How to use leaflet-pip plugin with pure GeoJSON data?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, point-in-polygon

I have trouble with using leaflet-pip:
i get geojson data from here: http://polygons.openstreetmap.fr/get_geojson.py?id=1320234&params=0

How should i call leafletPip.pointInLayer with such data?
I have several attempts, but it returns empty array, but i know that there are some markers inside those layers.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, note first that [Leaflet-PIP](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-pip) needs an `L.GeoJSON` group to be passed as 2nd argument. It is trivial to build one from your GeoJSON data (`L.geoJson(myGeoJSONdata)`). Actually, it even just needs an `L.LayerGroup`.

Then, it seems that Leaflet-PIP does not handle nested Layer Groups.

Your data is made of MultiPolygons, which Leaflet converts into groups of `L.Polygon` within the L.GeoJSON group. Therefore Leaflet-PIP does not process them.

So you just have to "flatten" your group before being able to use it correctly with Leaflet-PIP. Parse the group and extract all non-group layers into another group.

```js
var gjLayer = L.geoJson(myGeoJSONdata).addTo(map);

var groupOfNonGroup = L.layerGroup();

function copyToGroupOfNonGroup(group) {
  group.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    if (layer instanceof L.LayerGroup) {
      copyToGroupOfNonGroup(layer);
    } else {
      layer.addTo(groupOfNonGroup);
    }
  });
}

copyToGroupOfNonGroup(gjLayer);

var results = leafletPip.pointInLayer([lng, lat], groupOfNonGroup);
```

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/6hRKHHtvWOVdWg4jZ8AJ?p=preview

Comment: I've updated the leaflet-pip to a working link but this doesn't seem to work anymore, the resulting array is empty http://plnkr.co/edit/WtLDY9eL6ZpBUdeV8VQm

Comment: @Sam thanks for the heads up. I have updated the demo to use the new CDN for leaflet-pip and leaflet, but still version 0.7.7. Not sure what changed in leaflet-pip for leaflet 1.0?

Comment: Seems like leaflet 1.0 isn't supported by pip (yet?) due to changes in how Polygon classes are typed in the 'draw:created' argument (e.layer isn't the same signature anymore) ... shame :(